# How to overwrite a tag in jenkins dsl in configure

Tags: jenkins, perforce, jenkins-job-dsl

I have following problem - I'm trying to overwrite sync options for perforce  so I'm tried to do:

```
configure {
    populate('class': 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.populate.SyncOnlyImpl') {
        have(false)
        force(false)
        quiet(true)
        parallel {
            enable(true)
            path("p4")
            threads(4)
            minfiles(1)
            minbytes(4096)
        }
    }
    revert(true)
}
```

However it adds a new `populate` node to configuration instead of overwriting it. How can I overwrite it?

Comment: There is `perforceScm` which seems to solve my X problem. I'm not sure if that should be answer or wait on Y solution for anyone who will find this page through Google.

Comment: Please include a complete example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You get in a Closure for the node which is a groovy NodeList (http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/NodeList.html): You can manipulate the NodeList.

Example:

```
configure { node ->                             
  node / populate / have('false')
  node / populate / force('false')
  node / populate / modtime('false')
  node / populate / quiet('false')
  node.populate[0].@class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.populate.SyncOnlyImpl"  
}
```

This will override the defaults for the *populate* options for example. Hope this helps.